# Check if a Kotlin variable is a function

Tags: kotlin

I am currently learning Kotlin and am working through the [By Example Guide](https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/). In the chapter Functional/Higher-Order Functions it explained how functions themselves can return functions with this example:

```
fun operation(): (Int) -> Int {                                    
    return ::square
}

fun square(x: Int) = x * x                                         

fun main() {
    val func = operation()                                          
    println(func(2))                                               
}
```

Since I had previously learned to check the type of a variable in a "when" block, I tried to do the same here. Checking if a variable is of type function.

```
fun operation(): (Int) -> Int {                                   
    return ::square
}

fun square(x: Int) = x * x                                       

fun main() {
    val func = operation()                                        
    when (func){
        is fun -> println(func(2))
        else -> println("Not a function")
    }                                              
}
```

But this throws an error "Type expected", I guess because fun in itself is not a type.

I tried searching for things like "kotlin check if variable is function" but all I could find where guides on how to check for primitives or classes, nothing even mentioned functions.

Comment: You don't need to check it. `func` is always a function in this case.

Comment: @Sweeper what if it said `fun operation(): Any {` instead?

Comment: @Sweeper I know that. But there might be situation where it isnt clear. E.g if the assignment is done inside a if/else. This was just the most simple way to show what I want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's suppose you know nothing about `func`. (`func` is of type `Any`) You can easily check that it is a function by doing:

```
if (func is Function<*>) {
    ...
}
```

Or similarly use `is Function<*>` in a `when` branch.

However, this doesn't tell you the number or types of parameters, or the return type. Since you want to call the function with an `Int` here, it is important that you also check that the function has exactly one parameter of type `Int`. You can add a number after the word `Function` to check for a specific number of parameters,

```
if (func is Function1<*, *>) {
    ...
}
```

But that's where the simple stuff stops.

It is very hard to check for parameter types. You cannot just do this:

```
if (func is Function1<Int, Int>) {
    ...
}
```

Because generics are [erased](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#type-erasure), the runtime is not able to distinguish between a `Function1<Int, Int>` and a `Function1<Foo, Bar>`, so you cannot check for a specific type parameter using `is`.

The only way I can think of is unfortunately, reflection.

```
// JVM only
if (func is Function1<*, *> && 
    (func as? KFunction<*> ?: func.reflect())?.parameters?.singleOrNull()?.type == typeOf<Int>()) {
    // this is an unchecked cast, which means the runtime won't check it
    // but it is fine, because the code above checked it
    println((func as Function1<Int, *>)(2))
}
```

`operation` can either return a `KFunction`, like your `::square`, or a lambda. If it returns a lambda, the [`reflect`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.jvm/reflect.html) experimental API (You'd need `@OptIn(ExperimentalReflectionOnLambdas::class)`) is used to turn it into a `KFunction`.

After we have a `KFunction`, we can inspect its single parameter (if it has one) and check if it is `Int`.

So checking for specific types of functions is quite a pain. I would recommend that you change your design to avoid doing this, if you ever find yourself needing to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do general check `is Function<*>` if you just need to find out  given `func` object is a function or not. Also you can do restricted check for more specific function signatures, e.g. check it's a function with N arguments.

In the following code checks are arranged from more specific to less specific:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val func = operation()
    when(func) {
        is Function2<*,*,*> -> println(func(4)) // function with 2 arguments
        is Function1<*,*>   -> println(func(3)) // function with 1 argument
        is Function<*>      -> println(func(2)) // function in general
        else -> println("Not a function")
    }
}
```

And the output of this code is `9` because `func` is both a "Function" & a "Function with 1 argument", but "Function with 1 argument" condition is matched earlier.

**P.S.** Function22 (f with 22 arguments) is largest built-in into Kotlin